# Overriding properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need your help to solve this.

CASE 1

```js
function TextCell(text) {
  this.text = text;
}

TextCell.prototype.value = 100

var cell = new TextCell("hello");
cell.value = 120;
console.log(cell.value);
```

Property *value* is overridden to 120

CASE 2

```js
function TextCell(text) {
  this.text = text;
}

Object.defineProperty(TextCell.prototype, "value", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 100
});

var cell = new TextCell("hello");
cell.value = 120;
console.log(cell.value);
```

Property *value* is not overridden to 120

Why? I know I can use get, set, but that's not the question.

Comment: `writable: true` if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. By Default it is set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you izengod

Comment: Why did I get downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

As per [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description)

> **writable**
>
> true if and only if the value associated with the property may be
>   changed with an assignment operator.
>
> **Defaults to false.**

You need to add `writable:true` in the property descriptor while defining the property.

```
Object.defineProperty(TextCell.prototype, "value", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 100,
  writable: true
});
```

**Demo**

```js
function TextCell(text) {
  this.text = text;
}
Object.defineProperty(TextCell.prototype, "value", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: 100,
  writable: true
});
var cell = new TextCell("hello");
cell.value = 120;
console.log(cell.value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much